# How to find F1 score in MaskRCNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I looked into several issues in MaskRNN github link, but I'm still unable to find the method to identify metrics like precision, recall, f1score,etc.

From inspect_balloon_model.ipynb,

```
# Run object detection
results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)
```

How can I compare the test images and predicted images to find f1-score?